# Arrow keys seem to be stuck on?

Tags: company-of-heroes

I'm not sure how it happens, but when I'm scrolling around the screen with the arrow keys, occasionally, the screen will start scrolling in one direction, even without me pressing the keys. It's like the keys are stuck on. This only happens in Company of Heroes and nowhere else.

If I press the arrow that matches the direction the screen is scrolling in, this phenomenon stops.

Can anyone help me get this to stop?

Comment: I am afraid that this is a common issue in more top-down games than just Company of Heroes. (League of Legends for instance) The only solution I've ever found was to do exactly as you described; pressing the matching directional keys. It isn't too bad, and you already know how to fix it!

This issue actually occurs in many games on occasion, some FPS' as well!

Answer (score -1):

This means that the event for release arrow up never got registered.

Most times this is implemented as

```
void onkeydown(KeyBoardEvent e){
    if(e.getKey()==K_ARROW_UP){
        startScroll(up);
    }else if(e.getKey()==K_ARROW_DOWN){
        startScroll(down);
    }
}

void onkeyup(KeyBoardEvent e){
    if(e.getKey()==K_ARROW_UP){
        stopScroll();
    }else if(e.getKey()==K_ARROW_DOWN){
        stopScroll();
    }
}
```

where `startScroll()` can be (incidentally) called multiple times without issue, or `stopscroll()` will stop all scrolling, or there is a threading issue.

Comment: I dont see how this is an answer this is simply just an explanation of why it happens but no info on how you could possibly prevent it.